# Navigator push need key?

Tags: flutter

Before the upgrade this code work just fine:
[code now with and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shZmI.png)

Now this dont work and come with this error:
[eror description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA05l.png)

Here the code:
[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSp9M.png)
[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYEwY.png)
Help please.

Comment: can you give screenshots of your productos code?

Comment: all of the 119 line of code? is not very pretty, but if you asking for errors theres non, just the same errors when i try to use navigator push  @Adithaz

Comment: 50 code from the top is good i think

Comment: i edit the ask @Adithaz

Comment: Please learn how to embed code in your post instead of providing screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Productos extends StatefulWidget {
   //You can delete this line below and the problem will be solved
   Productos({required Key key}) : super(key: key); //<--this line

   @override
   _ProductosState createState() => _ProductosState();
}
```

But, before you delete it, check one more time if you are needed this line. Press ctrl + f while you are on productos.dart and search for "widget.key". If there's none, you are safe to delete that line.

Answer (score 0):

No, navigator doesn't need a key. But look at your productos.dart in Productos class constructor you have a "required" keyword